# How to distribute horizontally a bubble chart in d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bubble-chart

I am creating a bubble chart using d3js v4. I have a 1000px width and 500px height svg and I want the bubbles to be distributed horizontally while grouped by category. To keep them grouped, I am using stratify. When I use pack layout, it makes the circles spread around in a circle pattern, so it gets limited by the height.

[image]

How can I distribute the bubbles more horizontally?

This is my code:

```
        let svg = d3.select('svg#circle'),
            width = 1000,
            height = +svg.attr('height');
        svg.attr('width', width);

        let stratify = d3.stratify()
            .id((d: any) => d.name)
            .parentId(function(d: any) { return d.categoryId; });

        let pack = d3.pack()
            .size([width, height])
            .padding(20);

        let root = stratify(this.subcategoryData)
            .sum(function(d: any) { return d.total; })
            .sort(function(a: any, b: any) { return b.total - a.total; });

        let node = svg.selectAll('.node')
                .data(pack(root).leaves())
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('transform', function(d: any) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; });

            let div = d3.select('body').append('div')
                .attr('class', 'tooltip')
                .style('opacity', 0);

            node.append('circle')
                .attr('id', function(d: any) { return d.id; })
                .attr('r', function(d: any) { return d.r; })
                .attr('class', (d: any) => `circle-${d.data.categoryId}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to increase the X translation like so :

```
.attr('transform', function(d: any) { return 'translate(' + d.x * 1.5 + ',' + d.y + ')'; });
```

multiplying that d.x should spread the circles. Maybe if it doesn't work with 1.5 try something more.

Hope I helped.

Comment: It does looks more distributed, but the problem is that after a multiply the x axis in the translation, the graph gets very dislocated to the right. How can I correct its position to be more centralized?

Comment: Well, I don't know what your data is but maybe you can first subtract the pixels you want to move the chart to the left with and then multiply Like this:
d.x - 100 * 2 . But it will be a better practice if you used a scale for the x and y check out d3.scale